# Можно ли реализовать кастомное хранение ресурсов?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Мне не нравится то, что ресурсы хранятся в "одной плоскости" => их имена должны быть уникальными...

Можно ли как-то реализовать собственное внедрение ресурсов в сборку, что бы был еще один какой-нибудь дополнительный уровень.

Т.е что бы можно было делать что-то типа этого:

```
Group1/image1.jpg
Group2/image1.jpg
```

Comment: Создайте ещё один resx ресурс - `Group2` в вашем посте. Работать будет ровно так, как и ожидаете.

Comment: @Monk и даже смогу его поимени получать через  Properties.Resource.[Имя]?

Comment: Properties.Resource - это обычный namespace. Где будете хранить ваши ресурсы, так и будете обращаться. Я бы скорее тогда смотрел в сторону  Properties.Group1,  Properties.Group2

Comment: Просто создайте директорию, положите туда файл (любой) и в свойствах файла выбрать что это Embeded Resource. Доступ будет по полному пути, включая имя директории.

Comment: Чтобы иметь доступ по маске `Properties.Resource.[Имя]` надо где то в коде завести диктонарий, куда и сложить пути к ресурсам, или через xaml, если это WPF. Так кстати организованы библиотеки иконок, кистей и прочих свистелок. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf